# Extract and explore the File Modified Timestamp in .ZIP folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, event-handling

I need a files' modified time stamp within the .zip folder which is selected by the HTML file type element, using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do it using javascript.

Most likely you end up uploading the file to some php/linux server, then use php and shell commands to get the time stamp, and send it back to the client.

Comment: I can get single file's modified time, but i wish to get zipped files' property. jszip (http://stuk.github.io/jszip/) helps to some of the properties but not exactly my need.